# Report for Public Groups

Tags: dashboard, reports-api

I need to create 7 groups and track who has the biggest sales. 
Can I create a report about the group members's total sales and compare it to other groups? How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance. Respect post.

Comment: you could use a formula field, process-builder or workflow-populated or trigger-populated custom field that sets the Group Name for each Opportunity ; the trigger approach would at least let you dynamically discover the group name form the Oppo owner.  Of course, group membership can change and you'd need a batch process to periodically recalculate group names

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to implement in current Report builder, as you cannot select

```
Created by filter IN "SPECIFIC Group"
```

Best possible way to implement this will be to :

1. Create different reports with criteria as

   "Created by" equals "user id" 
   AND repeat this for all group members. This way you can compare reports for all different groups.
2. Create a joined report for all the groups and define separate filters for each section. You will be able to compare all revenues for different groups in a single report.